# Delphi: Unable to open .bmp file

Tags: image, delphi, bmp

I'm trying to load an image into a stringgrid cell

```
if CheckBox5.Checked = True then
 begin
    Ver :=  Ver + 1;
    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile('media/belgie_vlag.bmp');
    Form3.StringGrid1.Canvas.StretchDraw
    (Form3.StringGrid1.CellRect(Hor,Ver),Bitmap);
    Bitmap.Free;
 end;
```

When I run the application, an error shows saying the .bmp file cant be opened. Any help?

Comment: Why do you imagine the OS knows where to look for the .bmp file?  There might be a million `media` folders on your system/

Comment: Are you sure the target OS deals with `/` as path separators and not \ (backslash)?

Answer (score 4):

The most likely problem is that the file cannot be found, because you didn't specify an absolute path. You should *always* use absolute paths (e.g., `C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\image.png`, not `image.png`).

For instance, if the `media` folder is a sibling to the executable file, the absolute path is `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'media\belgie_vlag.bmp'`.

The following code should then work:

```
if CheckBox5.Checked then
begin
  Ver := Ver + 1;
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'media\belgie_vlag.bmp');
    Form3.StringGrid1.Canvas.StretchDraw
      (Form3.StringGrid1.CellRect(Hor,Ver),Bitmap);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Notice a few more things:

1. You must *always* protect resources with `try..finally` blocks, as above. Otherwise, in this case, if an exception is raised when you load or draw the image, you will leak the image object, making your application eat memory and get a limited lifetime.
2. There is no need to write `if mybool = True then`; `if mybool then` is enough.
3. You should only draw in the string grid in the appropriate event handler. I cannot tell where your code is placed, so I don't know if you are doing it the right way or not.